# How to return progress value from program

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, return, progress

How can I return progress value from C program?

For example on windows taskbar:

[image]

____________________________________________^ This progress, How windows knows it?

Is it something visual studio only supports on something simpler!!!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate, but it seems that all of the others are talking about C#, whereas this is talking about C.

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of `CLSID_TaskbarList`, and use the `ITaskbarList3` interface. Read, for example, [this MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942846.aspx#id0420051).

You'll need to use COM from C. It's perfectly possible, but good luck with that.